# Draw a line in the center of a chessboard

Tags: chess

I am trying to reproduce the following:

[image]

My best attempt so far uses `skak`.

```
\begin{figure}
    \newgame
    \showallbut{P,p,K,k,R,r,Q,q,B,b,N,n}
    \showboard
    \caption{The Frontier Line}
\end{figure}
```

How to add the central line?

*Note*: Please do not consider font, caption…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\chessboard[pgfstyle=topborder,markregion={a4-h4}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry. But why is there a white square on the right behind to h?

Comment: @Sebastiano That is the mover, it shows who's turn it is to play (but it can be removed, there is an option)

Comment: I used `\chessboard[showmover=false, pgfstyle=topborder, markregion={a4-h4}, label=false]`